# Objective-C and the self keyword

Tags: ios, objective-c

Good evening all,

I've researched this topic before on here but I'm still very much confused because I didn't see a good example of the use. I'm currently following along with this video and this is what he did:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *videoList;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.videoList = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

Ok, is the reason he used the `self` keyword here because he was basically saying use "this" property named `videoList` from this implementation file?

I went ahead and moved that property to this implementations header file and this was still OK. I'm assuming it's because since I imported that header file it has access to that property? Again, why the `self` keyword? What is it saying now?

I know that if you declare a property in an implementation file then that implementation file is the only file that can use that property. Where if you were to declare it in a header file then any implementation file that imports that header file can implement that property. Let's say you have two header files with the same named property.

One header file:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *arr;
```

Second header file:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *arr;
```

If you were to import both of those header files into an implementation file would it cause an error or is this where the `self` keyword comes in?

Comment: `self` is just an object reference. Specifically it means “the current instance of this object”. Different classes can declare the same property and therefore is no conflict since you need to provide the object reference to access the property.

Comment: If you try to declare the same property twice in the same class then you will get an error

Comment: `Self` refers to the current instance. Think of it this way: All humans (barring an accident or other problem) have arms, and if you refer to *an arm* you can mean anyone's arm. If you say *my arm*, you're referring to a specific arm (an arm belonging to your**self**), not just the arm of anyone in view. Consider `self` as meaning *the one belonging to this specific object, not all objects of this type*, just like *my arm* refers to the one attached to my body and not yours.